# Another way to exiting IEX other than ctrl-C

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I know we can exit the IEX console with control-C.  I'm curious if there's a command to type into the console that would also do the same thing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I can think of 3 ways to quit an IEx shell:

1. The mentioned `<ctrl-c>` hit twice or once followed by `q` and then `<enter>`,
2. `<ctrl-g>` and then `q` + `<enter>`,
3. and finally `System.halt`,

but there is a difference between `System.halt` and the others.

Namely that `System.halt` "*halts the Erlang runtime*" and the others just "*quit the shell*".

When you have only one shell session running or the session is not attached to a separate runtime then both ways will produce the same result.
But if you have a session connected to a separate runtime e.g. via `iex --remsh` (remote shell) then running `System.halt` in it will halt the runtime and so make both shell processes / runtimes terminate. Just quitting a shell (via method 1. or 2.) will not stop the runtime it is connected to.

Conclusion: if you connect with your shell to other runtimes then know that `System.halt` will halt the runtime you have connected to. If you do not want to do it use other methods.

UPDATE: Recently I have also found out about `<ctrl-\>`. You can read more about it in [this article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/03/how-to-quit-the-elixir-shell-iex/):

> What I didn’t know is that you can exit the shell by sending Ctrl-.
> The shell will exit immediately. As far as I know, it has the same
> effect as aborting the shell in the Break command, it doesn’t affect
> remote nodes and it also works outside of iex (for example, you can
> use to terminate your tests).

Comment: There's also `:init.stop` which gracefully stops the erlang VM.

Comment: please improve your answer according to @raacer's structure and adopt his new information

Comment: @flp Please see my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085376/another-way-to-exiting-iex-other-than-ctrl-c/30095378#comment70835929_41253670

Answer (score 22):

1. **Disconnect** from shell and stop current node. This is what you need in most cases.

   1.1. **`Ctrl+\`** - standard method to quit the Erlang shell. See "4.4  How do I quit the Erlang shell?" in [Erlang -- Getting Started](http://erlang.org/faq/getting_started.html#idp31956336).

   1.2. **`Ctrl+C, a, Enter`** - via  the `(a)bort` command of the [Break](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.8.2/IEx.html#module-the-break-menu) menu.

   1.3. **`Ctrl+C, Ctrl+C`** - looks like undocumented feature of the Break menu.

   1.4. **`Ctrl+G, q, Enter`** - via the `q` (quit erlang) commant of the [User Switch](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-user-switch-command) menu (see [Erlang -- shell -- JCL Mode](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html#id260985)).

   **Note:** this leaves **remote node alive** if you have connected to it with `iex --remsh` (see `iex --help` and [IEx -- Remote Shells](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/master/IEx.html#module-remote-shells)).
2. **Shut down** the node you are connected to.

   2.1. [**`System.halt`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#halt/1) - quick and dirty shut down. The runtime system exits with status code 0 (clean exit without errors). You can also call [`System.halt(:abort)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#halt/1) to abort with core dump. Same as [`:erlang.halt`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#halt-0).

   2.2. [**`:init.stop`**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html#stop-0) ([`System.stop`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/6bfabdfb69a9c872ac846e958e1814ec6c2138f9/lib/elixir/lib/system.ex#L477-L507) in future versions) - clean shutdown. All applications are taken down smoothly, all code is unloaded, and all ports are closed before the system terminates by calling [`halt(Status)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#halt-0).

   **Note:** this leaves **your shell alive** if you have connected to a remote shell with `iex --remsh`.

Notice that all these options are disabled if Erlang is started with the ignore break, +Bi, system flag: `iex --erl +Bi` (which can be useful, for example when running a restricted shell). See [Erlang -- erl](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) for more info.

Comment: Why did you feel compelled to restate answers that are already present?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Because the best answer is too complicated, does not have clean structure, and contains no links.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci and btw, I think some explanations in the best answer are not really correct.

Comment: Hi, here is the author of "the best answer" :) I think that Your answer is now better than mine. I have up voted it.

On the other hand @OnorioCatenacci is right. He is right that your answer contains mostly the same information like mine answer, and he was likely suggesting that you could just reformat my answer, fix some things and exited them than duplicating things.

Comment: @flp mentioned that I should update my answer using the information and structure you have provided - I would be glad to do it, but I don't want to build on other people work, so I would feel better if You or another user did it :)

Comment: @SzymonJeż Hi! Thanks for your vote. While I mostly agree, there is one thing to note. I was completely unsatisfied with your answer, not just with structure. So I have spent a lot of time for my own research and compiled my own answer from my point of view. There are some differences, probably minor, but I feel they are important. This is why I've created new answer. I think you wrote some wrong and non-accurate things, but I may be wrong too. There are many another questions that also have several similar answers. So I don't see any problem. Let people choose by voting.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like

```
 System.halt
```

also works.

Comment: run 'h System.halt' to get info on additional arguments you can pass into it

Answer (score 5):

input in shell 
 `:c.q()`
and be happy

Answer (score 1):

I always thought **ctrl-G**
followed by **q**
for quit
was the official way to exit the iex shell.

See the IEx docs' [section on the BREAK menu](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-break-menu), which also shows how you can switch between alternate shells etc.

Comment: There is nothing about `q` on the specified page. Just a short note that the BREAK menu may be used to quit. But the menu itself also does not contain the `(q)uit` option, so this look completely undocumented for now.