# Can I customize Elixir iex to exit with ctrl-D?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I know [several ways to quit `iex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085376/another-way-to-exiting-iex-other-than-ctrl-c) but I'd love to use ctrl-D like in other REPLs (e.g., `node`, `irb`.)

How can I customize `iex` to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible AKAIK, but one *can* use `ctrl-\` to exit Iex and Erl.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, this is not possible right now. IEx operations support comes directly from the Erlang shell, and this is not implemented in Erlang.

Most probably it won't be ever implemented either - this change was already proposed and rejected: https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/983

Comment: thanks for the link! I don't (yet) follow the reasoning behind the "no ctrl-D" decision but it's good to know that it's intentional. Customizing `iex` to exit on ctrl-D may not be wise but I'm still curious if it's possible.